# Changing SO-Pin in PKCS11 Interop

Tags: pkcs11interop

A straightforward question. Do you have any idea if there is a possibility to change the SO-pin of a token (ePass2003 in my case) using pkcs11 Interop? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Right now I can't find my ePass2003 to test but I would try with this code:

```csharp
using Net.Pkcs11Interop.Common;
using Net.Pkcs11Interop.HighLevelAPI;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string pkcs11Library = "opensc-pkcs11";
        static string oldSoPin = "1111111111";
        static string newSoPin = "2222222222";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Pkcs11 pkcs11 = new Pkcs11(pkcs11Library, AppType.SingleThreaded))
            {
                Slot firstSlot = pkcs11.GetSlotList(SlotsType.WithTokenPresent)[0];
                using (Session session = firstSlot.OpenSession(SessionType.ReadWrite))
                {
                    session.Login(CKU.CKU_SO, oldSoPin);
                    session.SetPin(oldSoPin, newSoPin);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tkanks a lot. I will try it tomorrow... today, actually. But I feel it will work 'cose one can change the logged in one's pin, I guess. BTW, thank you for your work at pkcs11Interop